# Java: -Dhttps.proxyHost not being used

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, proxy

I have a java application running on Tomcat in EC2 and I would like to reach a different EC2 endpoint via a proxy.  Let's call the source `https://source.com` and destination `https://destination.com` and the proxy `https://proxy.com`

The symptom I have is the following:

1. Hitting the endpoint from my source server works:

   - `wget destination.com` returns an output including connecting to the proxy and then connecting to `destination.com` with a 200 ok.
2. When I try to make the call using postman via the API on the source, I get the below error:

`org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://destination.com": Connect to destination.com:80 
...
connect timed out; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException`

**Things I've done:**

- Verify that the http and https proxy is exported

  - I have both of these exported as an environment variable:
  - `http_proxy=http://destination.com:80
    https_proxy=http://destination.com:80`
- Verify that java_opts include the proxy info as well:

  - running `ps -ef | grep app_name` returns the following:
  - `-Dhttp.proxyHost=destination.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyHost=destination.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=80`

Even with these information exported and in the java_opts (set in `setenv.sh`), it seems like the API is not using the proxy to reach the destination, because from the server, I can use wget/curl to reach the endpoint via the proxy.  Could there be another reason/location that I missed which is causing the API to not use the proxy?

My java version here: `java -version
java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't using the Java API. `http[s].proxyHost` is for `HttpURLConnection` and friends. You appear to be using the Apache HTTP client, which evidently doesn't support them.

Comment: thanks for your response. Are you saying I'm using Apache HTTP client because if I was using Java API, the above information is sufficient enough to make it work? Sorry, my friend mainly coded around this area and I don't have all the background on it.

Comment: @Calpis You are evidently using the Apache HTTP client because of the exception that was thrown.